# Delete query in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I want to delete rows from multiple tables. I know the select query, but I need an exact delete query for all the columns that are defined below:

```
SELECT j.application_id, 
       j.first_name, 
       j.last_name, 
       c.description, 
       l.description, 
       p.description, " +
      "j.email, 
       j.date_applied, 
       j.application_status, 
       j.dob, j.current_city, j.phone_mobile, j.phone_residence " +
 "FROM jobapp.job_applications j,
       jobapp.countries c, 
       jobapp.countries l , 
       jobapp.job_locations p " +
"WHERE j.preferred_location = p.id 
   AND j.current_country = l.id 
   AND j.nationality = c.id "; //+
  //"and application_status like ? and first_name like ? and last_name like ? and email like ?";
```

The query works fine using MySQL, but I need an delete query for the exact columns where the rows are get deleted...

Comment: You just want to delete the applicant, right?  You're not interested in removing rows from countries and job_locations, I asssume.

Comment: We don't write it for you; consult the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: @OMG, that was helpful.  He's new, why not point him to [ask]?  Maybe you should brush up on http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette.

Comment: @Paul: Not every account is as "new" as you think it is.  Maybe you should participate in the community you appear to have more interest in moderating.  That means doing things like linking to documentation that actually addresses the question at hand...

Comment: @Paul: You're clearly more interested in stalking & hounding those who actually contribute to SO, otherwise you'd have provided an answer based on the link I provided.

Comment: You have made **no** attempt to even paste in your code properly. This is *not* a "do my work for me site"

Comment: @OMG you dont have to write the code its just how to do it am not much expert like you but somehow i know it in general. From the above query i want to delete the rows of the exact columns in multiple tables that's where i got stuck  so if you prefer not to, it doesn't matter as technology is vast

Comment: Hello mr.@Bohemian don't think as a home work yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete statements are structured like:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE condition.
```

you should replace condition with the primary key from you query above (if it is present) and reference each table one at a time.